# Is there a way parse in this manner using strtok()? If not strtok() is there some other way?

Tags: c, parsing

I wish the parse the following string using `strtok()`.

```
DINNER;NME=Tom Johnson;ADRES=1234 Street;TIME="12:00","15:00":Formal
```

Is there a way I can get what's on the left hand side of the delimiter and after storing that value in some other variable I want that part to be deleted.

Example:
So if I choose the delimiter to be `;` in the above string. I want `DINNER` to be stored in variable and then `DINNER` is deleted from the string I was parsing. So the string would now look like this:

```
NME=Tom Johnson;ADRES=1234 Street;TIME="12:00","15:00":Formal
```

Is there anyway I can do this? If it is not possible with `strtok()`, is there some other way I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you call `strtok` it will return a pointer to the first token. The next time a pointer to the next token. E.g.

```
char *din = strtok(text, ";"); // "DINNER;NME=T  ...
char *nme = strtok(NULL, ";"); // "NME=Tom John  ...
```

Note that you have to pass a `NULL` pointer after the first call. This doesn't mean that the first part of the string gets deleted, you just get a pointer to another part of the string. Also, `';'` is replaced by a null-terminating char.

If you absolutely want to "delete" the first part you will have to copy the part you want to keep. E.g.

```
char *keep = strdup(nme);
free(text);
```

Comment: what if after the first strtok "strok(text, ";");" I call another strok with NULL as you said, but this time I change the delimiter. Eg: "strok(NULL, "=");" (Note that this is after the first strtok call). Would is still work the same way?

Comment: @Brandon yes you can specify different strings as delimiters in successive calls that parse the same string

Comment: but I would have to maintain the "NULL" in all calls after the first right?

Comment: @Brandon yes. You would pass another `char*` instead of `NULL` to start tokenizing another string. That's why you can't use `strtok` for multiple strings at the same time. There is `strtok_r` for that purpose.

Comment: One last question, if I would but the strtok in an if statemnt Eg: if(strtok(text, ";") != NULL); would it still process the strtok? I mean would the pointer move to the next delimiter? Or will it stay in its place to since it is in a if Statment. If it does move, is there anyway I could bring it back to the last delimiter it moved from? Thanks for you help.

Comment: If `strtok` returns a non-null pointer you would lose that pointer. In that case declare a variable first `char *tok;` and use this (ugly) if : `if ((tok=strtok(text, ";")) != NULL)`. You can "move" `strtok` back if you have kept a pointer and pass as argument. Then null-chars that `strtok` introduced will still be there mind you

Answer (score 2):

Use `strpbrk()` instead, example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[] = "DINNER;NME=Tom Johnson;ADRES=1234 Street;TIME=\"12:00\",\"15:00\":Formal";
    char *tail;
    char *token;

    token = string;
    while ((tail = strpbrk(token, ";:")) != NULL)
    {
        *tail++ = '\0';

        fprintf(stdout, "Token: `%s'\n", token);
        fprintf(stdout, "Right Side: `%s'\n", tail);

        token = tail;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Learning `strpbrk()`/`strchr()`/`strstr()` is better because `strtok()` has problems, for example parsing multiple strings at the same time is not possible, or using it with threads also not possible.

Comment: Could you please explain to me what "+tail++ - '\0';" and "token = tail" do? I am a bit confused about what they do.

Comment: Yes sure, `tail++ = '\0';` puts a `nul` terminator (*replaces the `;`*) so that `token` points to a string starting at the beginning of `string` or at the next character after the last `;` and ending at the current `;`. And at the same time it increases the pointer by one so that `token = tail;` continues parsing the string after the `;`.

Comment: Is there a way to make the delimiter either ";" or ":" and perform the exact same way as above.

Comment: based on the man page it looks like it functions the exact same way as strchr() right? Just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes, but the difference is that it uses a string as a *list* of possible delimiters.

Comment: Sorry, I one last question. As you mentioned, if I use strbrk() with 3 delimiters for example, is there a way to know know which one of those 3 delimiters cause the the string to be parsed? So if the delimiters are (;:=) and (;) was the first one reached that cause it to be parsed, is there a way to find out that it was (;) and not (:) or (=). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Brandon, sadly no. You can instead try a delimiter and if it fails, try the next one and so on. You could have a function that does that and tells you which delimiter matched. I remember having to do that somewhere just don't remember where. I remember that I used a function like `char *check_delimiter(const char *source, const char *const delimiter_list, char *found_delimiter);` (*behaving essentially like `strpbrk()`*) and passing the address to a `char` as the last parameter to store the delimiter that matched (*based on `strchr()` of course*).